# image license issues with fullscreen website background

Tags: web, background, licensing, fullscreen

This question is more license related then technical, hope this is OK for you.

We have a website with fullscreen background images. Now we figured out that companies like istockphoto or shutterstock don't allow you to show images bigger than 1200x800 on websites.

Do you know: 
- are there some companies who do have licenses for fullscreen website backgrounds?
- are there technical ways to circumvent copying of images and therefor licenses which allow the protected use of hires-images?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing or legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274963/questions-about-licensing/274964#274964) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139804/can-licensing-questions-ever-be-on-topic) for details, and the [help] for more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, any image you'll display in an HTML based web-size can't be protected from being downloaded. There are ways to make that task more complex for novice users, such as adding it as a CSS background, forbidding the right-click, etc... but it won't resist more advanced users and firebug like tools.

Another possible solution is to add a copyright at the bottom of the picture and make it so it is not visible in the fullscreen mode via CSS (make the image larger than the screen), but it will be displayed once downloaded. A great example:

- Look at the photo on this web-page: http://1x.com/photo/46293/all/latest-additions/childhood-beauty
- Try to see the photo only now and see the copyright message at the bottom: http://imghost.1x.com/46293.jpg

Finally, regarding getting licecenses for fullscreen website backgrounds, you'd be better of either creating your own pictures if possible, or directly contact the author of the photos to ask if they accept it. Also various free stock exchange web-sites exists such as http://www.sxc.hu/ which might not provide the best quality but at least they will suit your conditions. Alternative web-sites with free or public-domain photos:

- http://www.publicdomainpictures.net/
- http://gimp-savvy.com/PHOTO-ARCHIVE/
- Various public domain sources: http://www.publicdomainsherpa.com/public-domain-photographs.html